# How to use same instance of IdentifierGenerator for all mappings

Tags: java, hibernate

When using IdentifierGenerator like

```
<id name="id" column="id" type="long">
    <generator class="com.persistence.generator.CustomGenerator">
        <param name="max_lo">5</param>
        <param name="sequence">A_SEQ</param>
    </generator>
</id>
```

Hibernate instantiates the CustomGenerator class per class mapping if the same CustomGenerator class is used in multiple class mappings.

Is it possible to generate a single instance only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure you can share an instance, but you could certainly code a lightweight proxy generator to do it for you, like this (I'm using statics here for brevity, but this could easily be a singleton pattern or similar):

```
import org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerator;

public class SharedGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {
    private static final IdentifierGenerator underlyingGenerator = new UUIDGenerator();

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor sessionImplementor, Object o) throws HibernateException {
        return underlyingGenerator.generate(sessionImplementor, o);
    }
}
```

Then use the SharedGenerator in your Hibernate config as all instances will call the same instance of the underlying generator.